# Create a New Cumulative Column using DISTINCT

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to create a column of running totals based on a previous column.  However, the previous column contains multiple iterations of one value.  I need to be able to add my next value to just one unique value (not all iterations of it).  Please see the referenced Excel screenshot for a better explanation. Please notice that the values will need to keep "Project" and "Sprint" in mind as filter criteria.

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `Sprint` column data type is `Whole Number`, you can use `SUMX`.

### Calculation: Calculated Column

```
Cumulative Points = 
VAR SelectedProject = [Project]
VAR SelectedSprint = [Sprint]
VAR FilteredTable =
    FILTER ( 'Table', [Project] = SelectedProject && [Sprint] <= SelectedSprint )
VAR Result =
    SUMX (
        SUMMARIZE ( FilteredTable, 'Table'[Project], 'Table'[Sprint], 'Table'[Points] ),
        [Points]
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

### Output: `Table`

| Project | Sprint | Points | Cumulative Points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 30 | 30 |
| A | 1 | 30 | 30 |
| A | 2 | 40 | 70 |
| A | 2 | 40 | 70 |
| A | 3 | 25 | 95 |
| A | 3 | 25 | 95 |
| A | 3 | 25 | 95 |
| B | 1 | 10 | 10 |
| B | 1 | 10 | 10 |
| B | 2 | 20 | 30 |
| B | 2 | 20 | 30 |

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!!